# How can I get a loop to ignore non-letter elements in a list?

Tags: python, string, list, function

I have a string that contains letters and punctuation. I'm trying to replace only the letters in this string with other letters. The function I have developed only works for strings that contain letters. If numbers are included it produces a logic error and if punctuation is included then it produces a run-time error. Is there anyway that I can get my function to ignore punctuation and leave it as is while only operating on the letters?

```
#Create a string variable, ABjumbler generates an alphabet shifted by x units to the right
#ABshifter converts a string using one type to another

textObject = "g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb. lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj."
smalltext = 'abcde'

alphabet = list(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'])

def ABjumbler(alphabet, x):
    freshset = []
    i=0
    j=0
    while i<(len(alphabet)-x):
        freshset.extend(alphabet[i+x])
        i+=1
    while j<x:
    freshset.extend(alphabet[j]) #extend [0]
    j+=1 #change j = to 1, extends by [1], then by [2], and then terminates when it reaches x
    alphabet = freshset
    return alphabet

newAlphabet = ABjumbler(alphabet, 2)

def ABshifter(text, shiftedalphabet):
    freshset = []
    for letters in text:
        position = text.index(letters)
        freshset.extend(shiftedalphabet[position])
    final = ''.join(freshset)
    return final

print ABshifter(smalltext, newAlphabet)
```

Comment: `while j<x:` is not doing anything in your code because the block below it is not indented

Comment: Just curious - this looks remarkably familiar - one of the early pythonchallenge.com puzzles iirc ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one, there are some faster/simpler ways of doing the shifting you want.

But to answer your question, you could simply add:

```
if not letter.isalpha():
    continue
```

`str.isalpha()` returns `True` if the string is composed only of alphabetic letters.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it set me off on the right path anyway. I know there are simpler ways to do it, but I'm not as familiar with it. Once again, thanks for the help.

Comment: Yep, it turns out .isalpha() is all I needed to finish this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
textObject = "g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb. lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj."
smalltext = 'abcde'

alphabet = list(['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'])

def ABjumbler(alphabet, x):
    #for x greater then alphabet length
    if x>=len(alphabet):
        x = x % len(alphabet)
    #return a dictionary like 'a':'c', 'b':'d' etc
    return dict(zip(alphabet, alphabet[x:] + alphabet[:x]))

def ABshifter(letter, alph):
    if letter.isalpha():
        return alph[letter]
    return letter

print "".join(map(lambda x: ABshifter(x, ABjumbler(alphabet,2)), smalltext))
```

Comment: This is the most complete answer. I didn't mention that I wanted to try this without creating a dictionary, but now that I've got the code for it I can start figuring it out later. Thanks again.

Comment: You call len(alphabet) twice, and there's no reason to even do the if check there.

Answer (score 1):

1)

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print x

y = list(['a', 'b', 'c'])
print y

--output:--
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Any difference?  Then don't call list() when it's unnecessary.

2)

```
x.append('d')
y.extend(['d'])

print x
print y

['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Any difference?  Then don't create a list with 'd' inside if it's unnecessary.

Your whole ABjumbler() function can be reduced to one line:

```
cypher = alphabet[x:] + alphabet[:x]
```

Examine this code:

```
import string

x = 23
letters = string.ascii_lowercase

print letters[x:]    #xyz
print letters[:x]    #abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw
print "-" * 10

cypher = letters[x:] + letters[:x]
print cypher         #xyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw

table = string.maketrans(letters, cypher)
```

The maketrans() function constructs a translation table like this:

```
letters:  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
 cypher:  xyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw
```

If the letters on top are found in a string, they get translated to the letters directly beneath them:

```
x = "aaa"
print x.translate(table)   #xxx

x = 'abc'
print x.translate(table)   #xyz

x = 'a1bc!'
print x.translate(table)   #x1yz!


x = '123a-b-c!!!!a.b.c456'
print x
print x.translate(table)  

--output:--
123a-b-c!!!!a.b.c456
123x-y-z!!!!x.y.z456
```

If x might be larger than the length of your alphabet, then write:

```
x = x % len(letters)
```

before constructing the cypher.

```
import string

def encode_it(str_, letters, offset):
    offset = offset % len(letters)
    cypher = letters[offset:] + letters[:offset]
    table = string.maketrans(letters, cypher)
    return str_.translate(table)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `string.ascii_letters` constant to check if your current character is a letter. Here's a snippet that replaces all letters in a string with 'x' (I know this isn't *exactly* what you want to do but it might get you started):

```
    import string

    s = "g fmnc, wma: bgblr?"
    sList = list(s)

    for i in range(0, len(sList)):
        if sList[i] in string.ascii_letters
            j[i] = 'x'
        s = ''.join(j)

    print(s) #'x xxxx, xxx: xxxxx?'
```